# Django password reset on custom user model on Django 1.5?

Tags: django, forgot-password, django-1.5

I have a custom `User model` like this:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=90, unique=True, db_index=True)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    external = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    deleted = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    purged = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    form_values_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    disk_usage = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=16, decimal_places=0, blank=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField()
    is_staff = models.BooleanField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField()
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField()
    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'galaxy_user'
```

I have created all the required templates for the password reset. My application name is fileupload. So when I do from this fro Django shell I get something like this:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> User.objects.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 256, in __get__
    self.model._meta.object_name, self.model._meta.swapped
AttributeError: Manager isn't available; User has been swapped for 'fileupload.user'
>>>
```

How can I make Django password reset to work on my custom user model. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`get_user_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model)

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

User.objects.all()
```

Comment: I am not looking answer for this. I want to know how to use django password reset with my custom user model.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = <path_to_your_custom_User_model>
```

To your project's `settings.py`